# IIS is not allowing to access a javascript file

Tags: cgi, isapi, restrictions

i have a web application. while running in my system integration environment, i get an issue while accessing my javascript file or an image file in my particular folder.

When i tried putting the complete URL in the browser, it gave me a following exception -
 
**HTTP Error 404.2 Not Found** 
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the ISAPI and CGI Restriction list settings on the webserver.

I googled this exception and found that i need to allow ASP.NET 4.0, 2.0, etc in the IIS's ISAPI & CGi Restrictions.. however, they were already in allow mode.

What next should i lookup?

Answer (score 0):

OK,, i got the answer

the HTTP Handler in the applicatin's web.config file was trying to execute via a aspnet_isapi.dll located in Framework64 folder of .NET Framework.. the target machine however is a 32 bit and i dont have this Framework64 folder on it..

i changed the path of the executable to point to the 32 bit's folder and it wrked :)